# how to get code coverage when running tests written in tavern with pytest, having nodejs app running in backend?

Tags: node.js, pytest, code-coverage, tavern

I have an API written in node js, and integration tests for endpoints written in tavern with pytest. I want to get code coverage of those integration tests after running. For now, the setup is; first starting node app, and running tavern test suites with pytest command.
See lots of scenarios but all have a consistency in btw test engine and app engine e.g python - python or js - js. How could I get code coverage of tavern tests suites w.r.t node app?

-UPDATE-

The API written in node js -v12.16.2- with nest js framework, we run app with nest start, and running tests written with tavern -v0.34.0- with pytest -v4.5.0- on the other tab against running api. And I want to learn how to get code coverage of app by being hit endpoints by test requests by tavern.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Give us more information about your problem: what have you already tried? What went wrong?

Comment: Happy to be here with a profile, after being unknown for years! I actually tried to use coverage.py, but it couldn't detect node engine as I see. And also tried to start app with istanbul and run tests, to see if istanbul could detect executed endpoints in backend, it gave nothing as well. @CelsoWellington

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 programs here:

1. The nodejs app
2. The tavern test suite

You're interested in finding the coverage of the nodejs part, which means you need to instrument that program.

I've only had a quick look around, but it would appear that using https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc is a good bet, meaning you can just run your server with `nyc` prepended to measure the coverage when you run the tavern tests.

Note: this is a vague answer, I will update if the question is made more specific.

Comment: I just inserted some updates on the question, I don't know if it is verbose as you asked. Actually I tried what you suggest and `nyc` caused running unit tests written with `jest` , and it outputs of unit tests. I mean it didn't recognize hits done by requests in tavern. I think insturementing is not enough to calculate coverage, the testing framework might be needed to be also configured to be recognized by `nyc`, which is the `jest` case in the scenario.

Comment: And how are you starting the app up with coverage? I was expecting something like `nyc nest start`

Comment: Yes exactly. It runs unit tests written by jest by default and prints those results. After some research I've found that (https://learn2automate.wordpress.com/2017/06/01/code-coverage-from-functional-tests-for-node-js-applications/ ): it says that running app like `istanbul cover server/server.js –handle-sigint` where server.js is entrypoint of the app and after running tests, it collects hit points on backend and output them when the user kill the app with CTRL+C. But it doesn't work for typescript project.